# BootstrapTable, No matching records found

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, bootstrap-table

For a few days I am busy solving following. I would like to load bootstrap table through a click into a `<div>`. My situation:

index.php

```
<div id="page-content">
<div id="data" class="animated"></div> on page load, loaddata
<div id="table" class="animated">
<table id="report-table" data-toggle="table"></table>                
</div> hidden, onclick hide #data and show #table
</div>
```

loaddata.php

```
$tab_id = $_POST['tab_id'];
$tab_name = $_POST['tab_name'];

$selectTabbladen = $gebruiker_data->runQuery("SELECT * FROM documenten LEFT JOIN relaties ON documenten.relatie_id = relaties.relatie_id LEFT JOIN clienten ON documenten.clienten_id = clienten.clienten_id WHERE documenten.tab_id = $tab_id ORDER BY document_datum"); 

if (!$selectTabbladen->execute()) return false;

if ($selectTabbladen->rowCount() > 0) {
    $tabblad_data = array();
    while ($tabdata = $selectTabbladen->fetch()) {
            $tabblad_data[] = array(
              "id"                  => $tabdata['id'],
              "document_soort"      => $tabdata['document_soort'],
              "voornaam"            => $tabdata['voornaam'],
              "relatie_naam"        => $tabdata['relatie_naam'],
              "tabblad"             => $tabdata['document_status'],
              "status"              => $tabdata['document_status'],
              "aanmaak_datum"       => $tabdata['document_datum'] = date('d M Y H:i:s'),
              "laatst_gewijzigd"    => $tabdata['document_datumgewijzigd'] = date('d M Y H:i:s'),
              );
    }

                print '</tbody>
                    </table>

                ';


    $json_data = json_encode($tabblad_data);

    print_r ($json_data);
}
```

ajax

```
    $('body').on('click', '.tab_data', function () {
    content.hide();
    $('#dataa').show();

    var tab_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loaddata.php",
        data: {
            tab_id: tab_id
        },
        dataType:"json",
        success : function(data) {   
            $('#report-table').bootstrapTable({
                data: data

            });
        }
    });
});
```

As result I'm getting:
No matching records found

Can you help me please. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to echo '$json_data' in your PHP file otherwise will be not returned to the data in the success function. Try to console.log(data) to see the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have passed your tab_id correctly then the problem is with your query

Instead of

```
$selectTabbladen = $gebruiker_data->runQuery("SELECT * FROM documenten LEFT JOIN relaties ON documenten.relatie_id = relaties.relatie_id LEFT JOIN clienten ON documenten.clienten_id = clienten.clienten_id WHERE documenten.tab_id = $tab_id ORDER BY document_datum");
```

try this

```
$selectTabbladen = $gebruiker_data->runQuery("SELECT * FROM documenten LEFT JOIN relaties ON documenten.relatie_id = relaties.relatie_id LEFT JOIN clienten ON documenten.clienten_id = clienten.clienten_id WHERE documenten.tab_id = ".$tab_id." ORDER BY document_datum");
```

**Updated**

Try this

```
$('#report-table').bootstrapTable({
   'load': data
});
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it. The query is 100% good because if i print_r ($json_data) i get data from mysql table. I think the problem is in the ajax success function.

Comment: I have tried it, i get No matching records found.
 I have tried: 
   { 'load': data}
   { 'load': json_data}
   {'load': tabblad_data}

array is giving me following information
    [{"id":"1","document_soort":"pdf","voornaam":"Dymo","relatie_naam":"Stg de tussen","tabblad":"afgehandeld","status":"afgehandeld","aanmaak_datum":"25 Dec 2015 18:01:34","laatst_gewijzigd":"25 Dec 2015 18:01:34"},{"id":"2","document_soort":"pdf","voornaam":"Dymo","relatie_naam":"St‌​g de Tussen","tabblad":"betaald","status":"betaald","aanmaak_datum":"25 Dec 2015 18:01:34","laatst_gewijzigd":"25 Dec 2015 18:01:34"}]